Optical illusion: Grey objects under colored noise sometimes appear as the complementary color?
I am trying to understand the difference between the two optical illusions below. Both have grey objects underneath a cyan noise pattern but with opposite illusions... why does the grey coke can under cyan pixelation look red, but the grey spheres under cyan stripes look cyan?




This is really interesting.. I would love to know the reasoning as well. However, I think this is a human physiology question not a graphic design question. And while understanding this may aid in design, knowing "how it happens" is about how the human eye works.

Apparently conggnitive sciences stackexhange got rolled into psychology.SE

This may also be on topic at physics.SE

Color vision process is something billion times more complex than generating RGB images on the screen. We have only some theories of what might happen between our ears. Physicists revealed the existence of the physical RGB wavelength filtering in our eyes in the middle of 1800's, but what happens after it is still only a bunch of theories (=guesses). Some of them can more or less successfully predict the experimental color vision test results.
In 1950's Edwin Land presented his famous color experiment (search for Land Color Experiment) which shows that a person can somehow see green and even blue based on his memories and some other in-brain mechanisms when there's actually available only different brightness and saturation levels of red. Our brain tries to make a good guess when the actual information is deficient. Red maybe is a good guess in the Coke can case.

I thought about the cocacola red being due to knowledge but this does not appear to be reason, The reason is most likley the eyes auto white balance. Your brain most likely assumes there is a cyan color cast on the image and tries to tone cyan down. thus since red is complementary to when you have no cyan in the image like in the coke can eyes see it as red. Not sure about the second image

Excuse me, but isn't that automatic white balancing a way to utilize some experience or inherited knowledge of how much cyan the usual light environment contains. Land didn't disclose that effect, but inserted the "see what you expect" part.

Maybe yes, no. Its trying to remove a constant tint of the vision (its the same thing that causes as blue and black, or white and gold dress meme). Though it is not terribly well known how exactly the machanism works. See  colour constancy.

And from where is taken the information to adjust the balance if it's never stored to the brain nor hederitarily included to the body mechanics?

We can read what happens in the preprocessing step. So while the brain is impossibly hard to decipher, vision processing starts in the neurons on the retina and the data transfer path we understand quite well. So we can read that in some cases the data is allready processed here. SO part of the preprocessing balances the singnal.

So it's built in the body mechanics. The remaining option would be "it's reasoned in the fly to be a good idea to be done".
